# Create shortcut for specific activity on home screen

Tags: android, android-intent, shortcut, intentfilter

I would like to give my users an option to create a shortcut to specific page within the app.
I've seen similar usage at Whatsapp when you long press a chat and you are able to create a desktop shortcut to this specific chat.

I've tried finding some documentation about this [functionality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4679022/how-to-create-a-shortcut-which-leads-to-a-non-launcher-activity) but couldn't get it working.
Here's what I have:

**activity which isn't the launcher activity (including the intent-filter)**

```
 <activity android:name="com.my.example.pages.Topics"
    android:parentActivityName="com.my.example.pages.Apps">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.CREATE_SHORTCUT"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

**createShortcut function**

```
 public void createShortcut(){
        Intent shortcutIntent = new Intent("com.my.example.pages.Topics");
        Intent.ShortcutIconResource iconResource = Intent.ShortcutIconResource.fromContext(getActivity(), R.drawable.app_logo);

        // The result we are passing back from this activity
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, shortcutIntent);
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME, "Shortcut Test");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON_RESOURCE, iconResource);
        getActivity().setResult(getActivity().RESULT_OK, intent);
        getActivity().finish();

        Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Shortcut created",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

**Manifest**

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT" />
```

I'm probably missing something since after calling the function I get the Toasts but there's no shortcut created and the app exits because of the finish() method.

To be more clearer - how do I create shortcut for non-launcher activity?

*I'm running the code within one of my viewpager fragments.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6988511/how-to-add-apps-shortcut-to-the-home-screen

Comment: With all the respect to the guy who answered, Whatsapp application doing it very good and smoothly. As a user I feel that this option is very useful and even necessary

Comment: Seems for this to work, "Topics" must be a launcher activity

Comment: Did you try the exact steps shown in the linked question?

Comment: @NanaGhartey why it has to be the launcher activity? You can see that Whatsapp chat's page isn't the launcher activity and the shortcut leads directly to the chat

Comment: @cygery The related question is targetting  for shortcut to the launcher activity. Google play already doing it for you

Comment: Then what exactly *different* do you want?

Comment: Shortcut to a non-launcher activity

Comment: Actually, Whatsapp start the main activity and from it it opens the person's chat. That's the reason when you press button it has the main home screen ready without loading it.

Answer (score 7):

Use this to create a shortcut for non-launcher activity.

```
    private void createShortcutOfApp() {

        Intent shortcutIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
            YourTargetActivity.class);
        shortcutIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);

        Intent addIntent = new Intent();
        addIntent
            .putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, shortcutIntent);
        addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME, "App shortcut name");
        addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON_RESOURCE,
        Intent.ShortcutIconResource.fromContext(getApplicationContext(),
        R.mipmap.logo_of_your_app_shortcut));

        addIntent
            .setAction("com.android.launcher.action.INSTALL_SHORTCUT");
        addIntent.putExtra("duplicate", false);  //may it's already there so   don't duplicate
        getApplicationContext().sendBroadcast(addIntent);
    }
```

Now add permission in manifest

```
<uses-permission  android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT" />
```

Now define

```
android:exported="true"
```

attribute in

```
<activity> tag
```

like

```
<activity
  android:name=".YourTargetActivity"
  android:exported="true"></activity>
```

This works like whatsapp app chat shortcut.

Comment: @juvi please check above answer

Answer (score 0):

After referring to the [link(pinned shortcuts)](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/shortcuts/creating-shortcuts#pinned), the following kotlin code worked for me

```
fun createWebActivityShortcut(context:Context,shortcutname:String,extra1:String) {

    val shortcutManager = ContextCompat.getSystemService<ShortcutManager>(
        context,
        ShortcutManager::class.java
    )

    if (shortcutManager!!.isRequestPinShortcutSupported) {
        val pinShortcutInfoBuilder = ShortcutInfo.Builder(context, "yourapp_"+shortcutname)
        pinShortcutInfoBuilder.setShortLabel(shortcutname)
        val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, null, context, YourSpecificActivity::class.java)
        intent.putExtra("extra1",extra1) //add as many extras as you like
        pinShortcutInfoBuilder.setIntent(intent)
        pinShortcutInfoBuilder.setIcon()//add your icon here
        val pinShortcutInfo = pinShortcutInfoBuilder.build()

        val pinnedShortcutCallbackIntent = shortcutManager.createShortcutResultIntent(
            pinShortcutInfo
        )

        val successCallback = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
            context, /* request code */ 0,
            pinnedShortcutCallbackIntent, /* flags */ 0
        )

        shortcutManager.requestPinShortcut(
            pinShortcutInfo,
            successCallback.intentSender
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this works on android 14 (api 34) also

```
public void createLauncherDesktopShortcut(Intent intent, @DrawableRes int iconRes, String title) {
  intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
  intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
  if (intent.getAction() == null) {
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
  }
  ShortcutInfoCompat shortcut = new ShortcutInfoCompat.Builder(_context, Long.toString(new Random().nextLong()))
      .setIntent(intent)
      .setIcon(IconCompat.createWithResource(_context, iconRes))
      .setShortLabel(title)
      .setLongLabel(title)
      .build();
  ShortcutManagerCompat.requestPinShortcut(_context, shortcut, null);
}
```

don't forget to add permission in manifest

```
<uses-permission  android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT" />
```

and add
android:exported="true" ahead of activity in manifest. e.g.

```
<activity
    android:name=".ui.sifr_in"
    android:exported="true" />
```

than call the function this way:

```
Intent shortcutIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), YourClass2createShortCut.class);
createLauncherDesktopShortcut(shortcutIntent, R.mipmap.ic_launcher, "shortcut by sifr")
```

copied from [here](https://www.tabnine.com/code/java/methods/android.support.v4.content.pm.ShortcutManagerCompat/requestPinShortcut)